# Are digital compact cameras with optical zoom and image stabilization reasonably shock-proof when turned off?

Tags: equipment-protection

I wonder how fragile are moving parts inside a compact camera with optical zoom and optical image stablization (e.g. Lumix DMC-TZ57).

Can it get damaged if taken for a jog inside a backpack?

Answer (score 1):

The slight shaking is not a problem. Just make sure there are no hard objects around it. Some padding at the bottom of the bag (folded T-shirt or sweater) may also prevent shocks if the bag is dropped on a hard surface.